# Get id of img inside selected li using document.activeElement

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my html code

```
<li id="liButton_1" tabindex="2" class="activeli">
<a onclick="ShowVideo('1');">
    <img id="ImageButton_1" title="Sister Teresa's Talk (Malayalam)" alt="Sister Teresa"
    s="" talk="" (malayalam)
    '="" src="http://www.braddockinfotech.com/demo/dvnonline/vod/timthumb/timthumb.php?src=wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Sr.-Teresa.jpg&amp;h=54&amp;w=109&amp;zc=1&amp;a=c" class="active"></a></li>
```

Ok when this `li` is selected it is accessed like `document.activeElement`.
How to select the `id` of the `img` inside the `li` using document.activeElement.(some thing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u got the li reference as active element

```
var activeEle = document.activeElement;
var imageID = activeEle.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery its pretty simple

```
$("#liButton_1").click(function(){
  var img_id = $("#liButton_1 a img").attr('id');
});
```

Not tested but hope will work